# When is $\frac{a^2+b}{b^2+a}$ an integer?

Tags: number-theory

Obviously with $a,b$ integers and $b$ can't be greater than $a$. I found some solutions, like $(12,8)$ and $(135,95)$ which give the integer $2$, and $(10,5)$ which gives $3$, but I can't find a relationship between the solutions.

Comment: There's a lot of solutions - there are $40$ solutions with $b < a \le 100$, as checked by computer.

Comment: I think you need to make your question more specific.

Comment: I don't know how to make the question more specific, as my problem is just to find a relationship between the solutions. Say for example that expressions is equal to $2$, is there a way to, given a solution, find another?

Comment: I found at least one infinite class of solutions. See my answer.

Comment: A [quick search in Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7Ba%5E2%2Bb%7D%7Bb%5E2%2Ba%7D%24&p=1) reveals this question: [Diophantine equation : $N= \frac{x^2+y}{x+y^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/40627). And if there are more copies of this problem on the site, the would not be very surprising to me.

Comment: If $b$ can be negative then $a=k+1, b=-1$ gives $\frac{a^2+b}{b^2+a}=\frac{(k+1)^2-1}{2+k}=k$.

Comment: A recent post about the same equation: [Prove or disprove that, for any $n \in \mathbb{N_+}$, there exist $a,b \in \mathbb{N_+} $ such that $\frac{a^2+b}{a+b^2}=n.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2802933). And the MO cross-post: [Prove or disprove that, for any $n \in \mathbb{N_+}$, there exist $a,b \in \mathbb{N_+} $ such that $\dfrac{a^2+b}{a+b^2}=n.$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/302416).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a fixed integer $k > 0$ we get solutions to
$$ \frac{x^2 + y}{x + y^2} = k $$ by a Pell type equation. It turns into
$$  (2ky -1)^2 - k (2x-k)^2 = 1 - k^3   $$

You asked about $k=2.$ There are two systems of degree two linear recurrences for $w^2 - 2 v^2 = -7.$

First we have $w_n = -1, 5, 31, 181, $ with $u_n = 2, 4, 22, 128.$ The orbit relation is 
$$ w_{n+1} = 3 w_n + 4 u_n, \; \; \; u_{n+1} = 2 w_n + 3 u_n.  $$
When $w \equiv 3 \pmod 4,$ we get $y > 0$ with $2ky - 1 = w.$

We also have $w_n = 1, 11, 65, 379, $ with $u_n = 2, 8, 46, 268.$ The orbit relation is 
$$ w_{n+1} = 3 w_n + 4 u_n, \; \; \; u_{n+1} = 2 w_n + 3 u_n.  $$
When $w \equiv 3 \pmod 4,$ we get $y > 0$ with $2ky - 1 = w.$

My take on the outcome is that it is not natural to require $y > 0.$ Makes it messy.

For example, with $w = 12875,$ we get $4y = 12876,$ $y = 3219.$ Also $v = 9104, $ $2x - 2 = 9104,$ $2x = 9106, $ $x = 4553.$ Alright, $x=4553, y = 3219.$
$$ \frac{x^2 + y}{y^2 + x} = \frac{4553^2 + 3219}{ 3219^2 + 4553} = \frac{20733028}{10366514} = 2  $$

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./Pell_Target_Fundamental
  Automorphism matrix:  
    3   4
    2   3
  Automorphism backwards:  
    3   -4
    -2   3

  3^2 - 2 2^2 = 1

 w^2 - 2 v^2 = -7

Wed Nov 29 17:05:09 PST 2017

w:  1  v:  2  SEED   KEEP +- 
w:  5  v:  4  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  -1 ,  2
w:  11  v:  8
w:  31  v:  22
w:  65  v:  46
w:  181  v:  128
w:  379  v:  268
w:  1055  v:  746
w:  2209  v:  1562
w:  6149  v:  4348
w:  12875  v:  9104
w:  35839  v:  25342
w:  75041  v:  53062
w:  208885  v:  147704
w:  437371  v:  309268
w:  1217471  v:  860882
w:  2549185  v:  1802546
w:  7095941  v:  5017588
w:  14857739  v:  10506008
w:  41358175  v:  29244646

Wed Nov 29 17:06:09 PST 2017

 w^2 - 2 v^2 = -7
```

Comment: Nice. I think you have $w^n$ where you mean $w_n$ in a couple of cases. Can this generate solutions for any $k$?

Comment: @martycohen I see about the $w^n.$ At the main question, there is now a comment with a link to an answer by Gerry Myerson, years ago. He does talk a little about $k$ square, which I was ignoring. For nonsquare $k,$ I am a little less sure than I was last night about infinitely many solutions; There are certainly such for the Pell thing, but the necessary congruences for integral $x,y$ are not as clear as I had hoped.

Comment: @WillJagy: There are infinitely many solutions of this problem for when $k$ is not square and you can see my proof here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2802933/prove-or-disprove-that-for-any-n-in-mathbbn-there-exist-a-b-in-math/2818847#2818847 Do you know any topic discussing square $k$?

Answer (score 2):

I have found three
infinite classes of solutions to
$a^2+b = n(b^2+a)$.
These were derived
assuming that
$a$ and $b$
are relatively prime.
All three have been 
verified by Wolfy.

Note added later:
Two other solutions
are
$a=5, b=2, n=3$
and
$a=5, b=3, n=2$.

The first two are
one-parameter solutions,
the parameter being $m$.

The first is

$n=m^2+m+1,\\
a
=m^3+m^2+2m+1,\\
b 
= m^2+1
$.

The second is

$n
=2m^2-m+1,\\
b 
= 2m+1,\\
a
=4m^2+1
$.

The third is a two-parameter
solution,
the parameters being
$u$ and $k$.

$n
=u^2k^2-2uk+k+1,\\
b 
= u^3k^2-3u^2k+3u+uk-1,\\
a
=k^3 u^4 - 4 k^2 u^3 + 2 k^2 u^2 + 6 k u^2 - 4 k u + k - 3 u+2
$.

Amusingly,
if we put $u=0$
this gives
$n=k+1, b=-1, a=k+2$
which gives
$\dfrac{(k+2)^2-1}{3+k}
=\dfrac{k^2+4k+3}{3+k}
=\dfrac{(k+3)(k+1)}{3+k}
=k+1
$.
This is the same as
$a=k+1, b=-1, n=k$.

My work that follows
allows others to be
derived.

A more general class is

$n=m^2+k,\\
a 
=m(2m+\dfrac{m^3+1}{k})+k,\\
b
=m+\dfrac{m^3+1}{k}
$

where
$k | (m^3+1)$
(always true for
$k = m+1,$
$k = m^2-m+1$,
or
$m = uk-1$).

Here is my derivation.

If
$a^2+b = n(b^2+a)$,
then
$a^2-na = nb^2-b$
or
$a(a-n) = b(nb-1)$.

If
$(a, b) = 1$
then
$nb-1 = ma$
and
$a-n = mb$.

The following paragraph
is a new addition.

Note:
If
$m(nb-1) = a$
and
$m(a-n) = b$
then
$m$ divides both
$a$ and $b$
so $m=1$.
Then
$a = nb-1
=n(a-n)-1
$
so
$a(n-1)
=n^2+1
=(n-1)(n+1)+2
$
or
$a = n+1+\frac{2}{n-1}
$
so
$n=2$ or $3$.
If
$n=2$
then
$a=5, b=3$;
if
$n=3$ then
$a=5, b=2$.

Therefore
$a = mb+n$
so
$nb-1
=m(mb+n)
=m^2b+mn
$
or
$b(n-m^2)
=mn+1
$
so that
$(n-m^2)|(mn+1)$
and
$m^2 < n$.

If
$n = m^2+k$,
then
$mn+1
=m(m^2+k)+1
=m^3+km+1
$
so that
$bk = m^3+km+1
$
or
$b = m+\dfrac{m^3+1}{k}
$.

If
$k | (m^3+1)$
(always true for
$k = m+1$ and
$k = m^2-m+1$),
then

$\begin{array}\\
a 
&= mb+n\\
&=m(m+\dfrac{m^3+1}{k})+m^2+k\\
&=m(2m+\dfrac{m^3+1}{k})+k\\
\end{array}
$

If $k = m+1$,
this gives
$n
=m^2+k
=m^2+m+1
$,
$b 
= m+m^2-m+1
= m^2+1
$
and
$a
=mb+n
=m(m^2+1)+m^2+m+1
=m^3+m^2+2m+1
$.

If $k = m^2-m+1$,
this gives
$n
=m^2+k
=m^2+m^2-m+1
=2m^2-m+1
$,
$b 
= m+m+1
= 2m+1
$
and
$a
=mb+n
=m(2m+1)+2m^2-m+1
=4m^2+1
$.

If
$m = uk-1$,
then
$m^3 = u^3k^3-3u^2k^2+3uk-1$
so
$\dfrac{m^3+1}{k}
=u^3k^2-3u^2k+3u
$
and

$n
=(uk-1)^2+k
=u^2k^2-2uk+k+1,\\
b 
= u^3k^2-3u^2k+3u+uk-1,\\
a
= (uk-1)(u^3k^2-3u^2k+3u+uk-1)+u^2k^2-2uk+k+1\\
\quad=k^3 u^4 - 4 k^2 u^3 + 2 k^2 u^2 + 6 k u^2 - 4 k u + k - 3 u+2
$

(The expansion of $a$
was done by Wolfy.)

Comment: for a fixed ratio it is a rather unpleasant Pell type thing. There will be integer solutions for each ratio $k$ as the expanded Pell thing allows solution $(0,0).$

Comment: I didn't try that since this way worked. I would be interested to see your work that shows there are solutions for each possible ratio.

Comment: @martycohen: Do you know how to construct solution for $n$ which is a perfect square?

Answer (score 0):

A better equation to solve in General.

$$aX^2+bX=cY^2+dY$$

As already mentioned, the task is reduced to some equivalent to the Pell equation. Actually reduced to this form.

$$p^2-acs^2=\pm1$$

Solution we write.

$$X=\pm{s(dp+cbs)}$$

$$Y=\pm{s(bp+ads)}$$

Or so.

$$X=\frac{\mp1}{a-c}((b-d)p^2-(2cb-(c+a)d)ps+c(cb-ad)s^2)$$

$$Y=\frac{\mp1}{a-c}((b-d)p^2-((a+c)b-2ad)ps+a(cb-ad)s^2)$$

Or so.

$$X^2+Y=kY^2+kX$$

$$p^2-ks^2=\pm1$$

$$X=\pm{p(kp-s)}$$

$$Y=\pm{}s(kp-s)$$