# Solve over integers: $x(x+1) = 2y(y+1)$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, integers

Solving $x(x+1) = 2y(y+1)$
I've got this :
y = $\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2x^2+2x+1}$ so $2x^2+2x+1 = n^2$
so $x \equiv 0 \pmod 4$ or $x \equiv -1 \pmod 4$ and I totally stuck...

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: Also, consider [adding more tags](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9961). This will help your question become more clear as well as attract users to your question.

Comment: Try multiplying $2x^2+2x+1=n^2$ by $2$ and complete the square.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how $y = \frac 12 \sqrt{2x^2 + 2x + 1}$? I'm struggling to understand this.

Comment: Similar problems here to solve. It is better to have a General formula.   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2543688/when-is-fraca2bb2a-an-integer/2543998#2543998

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solving it as quadratic equation in terms of $x$ we have:

$$x^2 + x -2y^2 - 2y = 0$$

$$x= \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1 + 8y^2 + 8y}}{2}$$

Now we have that $8y^2 + 8y + 1 = m^2$, as $x$ is an integer. Again solving for $y$ we have:

$$y = \frac{-8 \pm \sqrt{64 + 32m^2 - 32}}{16}$$

So we must have that $2(m^2 + 1)$ is a square. So we get $n^2 - 2m^2 = 2$. This Diophantene Equation has infinitely many solutions. For example:

$$n_k + m_k\sqrt{2} = (10 + 7\sqrt{2})(3 + 2\sqrt{2})^k$$

generates infinitely many. Now note that the solutions for $n$ are even, but never divisible by $4$, so we have $m^2 + 1 = 2s^2$, where $s$ is odd. So:

$$y = \frac{-8 \pm 8s}{16} \in \mathbb{Z}$$

$$x = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{2s^2 - 1}}{2} \in \mathbb{Z}$$

So we have that each solution of $n^2 - 2m^2 = 2$ generates a solution of $x(x+1)=2y(y+1)$, so there are infinitely many of them. Some examples are: $(x,y) = (3,2),(20,14),(119,84),(696,492) \dots$

Answer (score 0):

$$x(x+1) = 2y(y+1) \Leftrightarrow 4x^2+4x=2(4y^2+4y)\Leftrightarrow \\4x^2+4x+1=2(4y^2+4y+1)-1 \Leftrightarrow (2x+1)^2-2(2y+1)^2=1$$

This is the Pell equation, you want the odd solutions to it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2543688/when-is-fraca2bb2a-an-integer/2543998#2543998